# Chromebooks Installed with Ubuntu 18.04 Sound isn't Working

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi, chromebook

I am working with a school and we had a couple hundred Lenovo N21 and N22 laptops donated to us. They were nearing the end of their support cycle so I am installing 18.04 on them using MrChromeBox's BIOS to enable USB bootup and doing a complete wipe of the ChromeOS and installing Ubuntu.

Everything works on the machines except the speakers which upon initial install only show *Dummy Output*. I have gone through the solution for the Dummy Output adding the `snd-hda-intel model=generic` to the config file and I do get HDMI/DisplayPort - Built-in Audio but nothing else and the speakers still don't work.

I have also tried installing the ALSA Drivers and components a second time, uninstalling and reinstalling Alsa, installing `pavucontrol`, to no avail. Is there anything else I can try to get the speakers functional?

I have done the following lines of code to verify the hardware is detected and have had the following outputs:

`lspci -nk | grep -i audio`

```
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series High Definition Audio Controller [8086:2284] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series High Definition Audio Controller [8086:7270]
```

`aplay -l`

```
\**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: chtrt5650 [chtrt5650], device 0: Audio (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: chtrt5650 [chtrt5650], device 1: Deep-Buffer Audio (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

`dmesg | grep -iE 'snd|hda'`

```
[    6.217817] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: Linked as a consumer to 0000:00:02.0
[    6.217925] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
[    6.841545] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input7
[    6.841799] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input8
[    6.842007] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input9
[    8.680703] cht-bsw-rt5645 cht-bsw-rt5645: snd-soc-dummy-dai <-> media-cpu-dai mapping ok
[    8.680764] cht-bsw-rt5645 cht-bsw-rt5645: snd-soc-dummy-dai <-> deepbuffer-cpu-dai mapping ok
```

Comment: First thing I'd try is to verify the hardware is detected, and if so, write down the specs to narrow the search field. `lspci -nnk | grep -i audio` `aplay -l` `dmesg | grep -iE 'snd|hda'`

Comment: @mikewhatever I have done as you suggested and have put up the results in the original post. I do not know though the specifics of what I am looking at so further help would be appreciated

Comment: Is there any update on this?